Decrease high response time when reading large table in MySQL
I have a table with around 80~ million rows called parts.
I have a simple query like this
SELECT line_code, part_number, compressed_part_number, ...[Others columns]
FROM parts  
WHERE (@partNumber = part_number OR @partNumber = compressed_part_number)
AND region = @region
AND @lineCode = line_code

I have separate indices in both columns part_number, compressed_part_number
The Explain for this query shows like this



#
id
select_type
table
partitions
type
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
1
SIMPLE
parts
NULL
index_merge
partnumber_idx, linecode_comprpartnumber_region_parttype_idx
123, 123
NULL
64706
0.00
Using sort_union(partnumber_idx, linecode_comprpartnumber_region_parttype_idx); Using where



The explain format json shows the following cost information:

Usually, the number of rows returned ranges between 4k to 6k. However, the first time the query is executed (for each combination of @partNumber and @lineCode), the response time takes more than 20s to finish (of course, subsequent executions of the same query finishes in less than 500ms)
If add a limit of, for example, 500, the query performs a bit better (3s~)
I have two cluster running in AWS RDS

Cluster A: db.r5.large (80M+ rows in parts table)
Cluster B: db.r6g.2xlarge (300M+ rows in parts table)
The same behavior is replicable in both clusters

The part_number and compressed_part_number are varchar(50) columns.
I assume the main bottleneck is the I/O process of reading and retrieving the data as the the read cost overwhelmingly exceeds the evaluation cost (I could be wrong interprating this, though).

Is it normal that mysql struggles to return considerable 2 to 5 thousands of rows in large tables?
Is there a way to improve the performance in this aspect? (I'm open to new ideas of structuring the information)
Are there other options in RDS to use faster disks, or even changing the configuration for innoDb could help?

Note: We need all the information, because we are doing other processing with all the rows. Pagination is not an option either.

Rewriting this query to
SELECT line_code, part_number, compressed_part_number, ...[Others columns]
FROM parts  
WHERE (@partNumber = compressed_part_number)
AND region = @region
AND @lineCode = line_code
UNION
SELECT line_code, part_number, compressed_part_number, ...[Others columns]
FROM parts  
WHERE (@partNumber = part_number )
AND region = @region
AND @lineCode = line_code

this code will profit from this index
(part_number,compressed_part_number, region ,line_code)

that would speed up.

According to the explain result, it's using merge_index, not a full table scan

the combined index like suggested doesn't need a costly merge
